# Login with cURL using POST

Tags: forms, post, curl, cookies

I have little experience with cURL, I have to login to a website using cURL and I think the best way is through POST method, then head to another URL and request a POST, in the same "navigation session", because I can only access the other URL logged in.

As far as I searched, I need a cookies file to keep me logged in, so I used this command to do that:

`curl --cookie cookies.txt --request POST 'http://example.com/' -F 'authenticity_token=TOKENWITHLETTERSNUMBERSANDSYMBOLS&uid=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD&commit=Enter --request POST 'http://example.com/subpage#40' -F 'commit=Save'`

But it didn't work, maybe because of the authenticity token, which is generated every time I enter the URL, it is accessible in this part of the HTML:

```
<form action="/login/log" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="e2IIs5+9p9bAqkE0gJ4nVJ5E+yhKGod2B9b1bj6VJNk=" /></div>
  <p><b>Login:</b> <input id="uid" name="uid" type="text" /></p>
  <p><b>Password:</b> <input id="password" name="password" type="password" /></p>
  <p id='submit'>
</form>
```

So how do I retrieve the authenticity token value to use it in the POST request? Also, is POST the best way of doing this?